# Conditional Correlation?

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

Given: I have columns something like

```
| Location  | Year | A | B   |
|-----------|------|---|-----|
| Delhi     | 1980 | 4 | 3.4 |
| Mumbai    | 1986 | 3 | 3.9 |
| Delhi     | 1990 | 5 | 4.4 |
| Bangalore | 1997 | 2 | 2.6 |
| Delhi     | 1998 | 4 | 3.8 |
| Delhi     | 1991 | 4 | 4.5 |
| Bangalore | 1987 | 4 | 3.8 |
| Mumbai    | 1998 | 5 | 4.8 |
```

And I want to perform correlation between column `A` and `B` under Delhi `Location` category.

I want to perform correlation with only **Delhi** as `Location`

```
| Location | A | B   |
|----------|---|-----|
| Delhi    | 4 | 3.4 |
| Delhi    | 5 | 4.4 |
| Delhi    | 4 | 3.8 |
| Delhi    | 4 | 4.5 |
```

I tried `CORREL()` function but this will give correlation `A` and `B` for all location. I just want specific `Location` to correlated.

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is some basic array formula filtering. By making each correlation range dependent on whether A2:A9 is *Delphi*, you create a conditional correlation.

```
=CORREL(IF(A2:A9="Delhi", C2:C9), IF(A2:A9="Delhi", D2:D9))
```

This is an array style formula. As such, you need to uses Ctrl+Shift+Enter to finalize the formula; not just Enter. If you do this correctly, Excel will wrap the formula in maths braces; e.g. **{** and **}**.

Using this method the answer to your sample data is 0.481869424652427.

Comment: I am getting `#VALUE!`. which says A value used in the formula is of the wrong data types. I am calculating this correlation in another sheet. Does it effect my calculation. Or there is something else.

Comment: It shouldn't matter if the table is on another worksheet. It shouldn't matter if there are numbers in the *Location* column and if there was text in any of the number columns, you would get a `#DIV/0!` error. I'm a little dumbfounded as to what the problem is.

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + Enter works. Thanks @Jeeped.